The type or namespace name 'Mocks' does not exist in the namespace 'PactNet'
I started diving into Contract Testing using a C# .NET 8 project. I have downloaded and installed the following packages.

When using PactNet.Mocks.MockHttpService; i am getting The type or namespace name 'Mocks' does not exist in the namespace 'PactNet'.
using PactNet gives no errors.
Any idea why I am unable to implement the .Mocks namespace?

I assume you are using https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v1?
This repo is out-of-date afaik. I started looking at https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/tree/4.5.0/samples/ReadMe and the readme found at https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/blob/4.5.0/README.md. I hope this helps.
